# Expresión regular en Javascript para números entre 3.0 y 5.0

Tags: javascript, regex

Intento realizar una expresión regular en Javascript para validar cadenas de texto que pueden ser de la siguiente forma:

1. Cualquier número desde 3.0 a 5.0 en saltos de a 0.1 (3.0, 3.1, 3.2...)
2. Los números 3, 4 y 5, y
3. Las cadenas 3., 4. y 5. (con el punto al final)

La expresión que obtuve para estos casos es `/(3|4)((\.?)|(\.[0-9]))|(5(\.?)0?)/` que me coincide con los números 3, 4 y 5 y las cadenas 3., 4., 5. pero no consigo los números como 3.1, 3.2, etc ni el 5.0 [como lo indica Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/qR2jK5/1) ¿Qué hice mal en mi expresión regular?

Comment: Parece que 5.0 sí lo reconoce

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Sí, pero a costa de reconocerme 50.

Comment: Cierto. Estás cosas están bien. Buena pregunta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prueba con la siguiente expresión regular:

```
[34](\.\d?)?|5(\.0?)?
```

[image: img]

Comment: Mucho más bonito que lo mío :)

Comment: con que hiciste esa gráfica?

Comment: @JavierCárdenas no es la primera vez que veo a alguien preguntando algo similar y creo que nunca le dijeron, asi que mirando por la web encontre esta web, no se si sera la misma que usa Paul Vargas pero la imagen que muestra es similar y tiene un link para embed en SO -> https://www.debuggex.com/ Saludos

Answer (score 2):

El orden de los factores afecta el resultado. En esta parte:

```
((\.?)|(\.[0-9]))
```

Primero viene la comparación con el `.` y luego con el `.x` (con x un número entre 0 y 9), así que se cumple la primera y se ignora la segunda. Una posible solución sería cambiar el orden:

```
((\.[0-9])|(\.?))
```

Con eso ya te reconoce 3.0, 3.1, 3.2...

Ahora, para aceptar el 5.0 pero no el 50, puedes seguir un método similar:

```
(\.?|\.0)
```

Con eso se conocería o bien la cadena vacía (para 5), o `.`, o `.0` pero ningún otro valor.

Juntando todos los cambios, la expresión regular quedaría así

```
^((3|4)((\.[0-9])|(\.?))|(5)(\.?|\.0))$
```

---

Notas:

- Este método puede que no sea el mejor (no soy experto en expresiones regulares), intenté ajustarme lo máximo posible a lo que ya tenías.
- Puse los caracteres de principio y fin de cadena para evitar cosas como 3.45, aunque los podrías eliminar si quieres quedarte con el valor de 3.4.
- Cambié los paréntesis para que la primera aceptada sea el valor, el segundo sea la parte entera y el tercero sea la parte decimal con el punto.